# gridMathematica: manual launching kernel on cluster node error

Tags: parallelization

I have a cluster with gridMathematica installed, and the version is:

```
Mathematica 7.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)
```

Command

```
In[1]:= $ConfiguredKernels
```

gives output:

```
{<<8 local kernels>>}
```

That command ran on the manager node of the cluster.  I want to add other nodes, so I tried the following commands:

```
In[1]:= Needs["SubKernels`RemoteKernels`"]
In[2]:= LaunchKernels[RemoteMachine["node1"]]
```

And I see next output:

```
bash: math: command not found

SubKernels`Protected`kernelFlush::time:
 Operation LinkWrite timed out after 15. seconds.

KernelObject::rdead:
 Subkernel connected through remote[node1] appears dead.

Out[2]= $Failed
```

Why did `LaunchKernels` produce `$Failed`?

If I go to node1 via ssh

```
ssh node1
```

I can't find gridMathematica software on this node (program `math`). Is that normal?

Comment: Have you asked the person who manages the cluster why you can't find Mathematica on node1? That seems to be the problem. On the cluster I use, all software is stored in modules that must be loaded on each node before use. For example, I run `module load mathematica` before `math` on each node. Your cluster may be different.

Comment: Thank you! I.e. Mathematica must be installed on every cluster node? How I can check it? I have to look 'math' program, or something else? What name of gridMathematica installation folder on nodes?

Comment: I edit my question -- I forgot quotes in command In[2]:= LaunchKernels[RemoteMachine["node1"]]

Comment: Each node needs access to the mathematica executable, otherwise it can't start any kernels. Re: how can you check if Mathematica is installed on each node? Well, you know from "command not found" that the shell can't find what it needs. I don't know about installation folders. You should ask the person that manages your cluster.